# How to pass an excel cell reference to a text box and preview the value?

Tags: vb.net, excel, excel-addins

I'm currently writing an addin in visual basic (with visual studio) for excel, which needs some input data from the user. I want the input data to be passed like in a normal excel function.

This means A dialog with a textbox where the user can either type in the value directly or click on a cell in a worksheet which then provides the number. Thereby the cells address is saved and furthermore the value is shown as preview on the right side. This user interface is common for the default excel function so i provided a screenshot below (Cos functions requires an argument which is passed as cell reference F13).

So I want the user to be able to click on a text box and open a dialog to select a cell on the excel sheet. This reference should be passed to the form and a preview of the content should be shown on the right. If Excel has this function by default i asked myself if there is a predefined control element or function.

Any hint would be helpful.

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your question? To address a cell like this, you can use a `Range` object, where you can specify a cell as `A12`. You can also address a cell by row and column number, but be carefull, indexes start at 1 and not at 0

Comment: Yes, sorry your're right i didn't make myself clear. I added a few lines and hopefully it becomes clear. thx

Comment: When you build a UserForm in Excel that control is called a `RefEdit` control. So it depends firstly on how much of your add-in is based on .NET or VBA code. There is an article [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gabhan_berry/2008/06/11/how-to-code-a-net-refedit-control/) discussing how this control could be coded, or replicated, from .NET.